# Latest xcode 6.3 update gives me a warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6.3

Recently I have updated my `xcode` to version `6.3`. I am getting the following warning message.

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesise property 'name'; It will
>   be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge
>   intention.

Can someone please help me out on this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class hierarchy there are two different definitions of the property `name`. If both of them are the same type and used for the same purpose, just delete the one declared in the subclass or substitute it with `@dynamic name;` if needed to keep the compiler happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can selectively ignore the warnings per file if the issue is in a third party lib, like in my case it's inside AFNetworking. So I disabled the warnings for all AF... files. By going to Build Phases then in Compiler Sources double clicking each file and adding a compiler flag
`-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker`